# Mouseover in jqtouch?

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

Is it possible to use mouseover or hover type functions on an iphone?  I'm trying to write code for a basic regional image map and cant get the hover function to work at all using either mouseover of hover. Just wanted the images to switch as users finger drags across the map.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQTouch you can use the events "swipe" and "tap" instead of "hover" and "click".

See -> h**p://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/wiki/callbackevents

The Apple documentation mentions the following on "hover":

> "...mouse events are emulated in Safari on iPhone OS. As a result, elements that rely only on mousemove, mouseover, mouseout or the CSS pseudo-class :hover may not always behave as expected on a touch-screen device such as iPad or iPhone"

source: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/index.html